# Google line chart goes to negative values if has only zero and positive ones

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I use Google chart to build graph. Here is my code:

```
var array = [["Day", "Value"], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 7], ["22", 0], ["23", 0], ["24", 0], ["25", 0]];
```

array of values has only zero and positive values

this shows only positive values

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);
var options = {
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: {position: 'bottom'},
    vAxis: {viewWindowMode: "explicit", viewWindow: {min: 0}, minValue: 0, maxValue: 4},
};
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

this shows negative and positive values

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);
var options = {
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: {position: 'bottom'},
    vAxis: {viewWindowMode: "explicit", minValue: 0, maxValue: 4},
};
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

[That is how graph looks like. Line goes to negative values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LYDB.png)

[If only positive values shown the line breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9743b.png)

How to show only positive values on graph? Without line breaking

Comment: If you want to show values without line breaking, you must to change negative values on something, on zeros for example

Comment: @Redair but I don't have negative values. I don't know why they appeared here

Answer (score 0):

If you use curveType: 'function' it is aproximate values. Just comment or delete this line:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);



      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["Day", "Value"], ["15", 0], ["16", 0], ["17", 0], ["18", 0], ["19", 0], ["20", 0], ["21", 7], ["22", 0], ["23", 0], ["24", 0], ["25", 0]]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          //curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution is good, but now the line on graph is not smooth anymore. Maybe there is another variant that keeps line curve?

Answer (score 0):

Make the graph minimum is 0, so it will not go negative.

```
          viewWindowMode:'explicit',
          viewWindow:{
            min:0
          }},
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution has worked for me.

> viewWindowMode:'explicit'   -- depericated now.

```
vAxis: {
    viewWindow: {
       min: 0
    }
}
```